# How to get total no of counts of json array?

Tags: android

How to get total no of counts of json array ?I want to get tolal no of id in json file we can see there is two id . So toltal no of  count should be two.

total no of count should be display two. Because in json two id is present. How can we get this count? 
see in the image what i am getting whole json . 
But i want only total no of count of "id" which is two after clicking the "leads" button.
lead.json

```
[
        {
                "id": "449876",
                "First Name": "Govind",
"Middle Name" :"Shripatrao",
"Last Name":"Suryawanshi",
"City":"Gurgaon",
"Country":"India",
"Contact No":"+91 8586925935",
                "email": "Suryawanshi.govind@gmail.com",
"Budget":"Starting at ?1.7 Crores onwards",
"Project":" -",
"App Platform":"UtilityApp-Android",
"Source":"Organic",
"Campaign":"NA",
"Lead Time":"11/8/2015 2:51:32",
"IP Address":"182.64.13.180"

        },
        {
"id": "425676",
                "First Name": "Karan",
"Middle Name" :"Singh",
"Last Name":"Rana",
"City":"Chandigarh",
"Country":"India",
"Contact No":"+91 9854563132",
                "email": "ranasinghkaran@yahoo.com",
"Budget":"Starting at ?3.35 Crore onwards",
"Project":" Myst",
"App Platform":"UtilityApp-Android",
"Source":"Organic",
"Campaign":"NA",
"Lead Time":"9/15/2015 12:05:28",
"IP Address":"182.71.22.178"

                }

    ]
```

Main Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import tatahousingleads.com.tatahousingleads.app.AppController;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    // json array response url
    private String urlJsonArry = "http://milagro.in/wip/apps/n/lead.json";

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnMakeObjectRequest, btnMakeArrayRequest;

    // Progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private TextView txtResponse;

    // temporary string to show the parsed response
    private String jsonResponse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // btnMakeObjectRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnObjRequest);
        btnMakeArrayRequest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnArrayRequest);
        txtResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResponse);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);



        btnMakeArrayRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // making json array request
                makeJsonArrayRequest();
            }
        });

    }







    private void makeJsonArrayRequest() {

        showpDialog();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            // Parsing json array response
                            // loop through each json object
                            jsonResponse = "";
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject lead = (JSONObject) response
                                        .get(i);

                                String id = lead.getString("id");
                                String firstname = lead.getString("First Name");

                                String middname = lead.getString("Middle Name");
                                String lanme = lead.getString("Last Name");
                                String city =lead.getString("City");
                                String country =lead.getString("Country");
                                String contactno =lead.getString("Contact No");
                                String email = lead.getString("email");
                                String budget = lead.getString("Budget");
                                String project = lead.getString("Project");
                                String appplatform = lead.getString("App Platform");


                                jsonResponse += "Id: " + id + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "First Name: " +firstname  + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Middle Name: " + middname + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Last Name: " + lanme + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "City: " + city + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Country: " + country + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Contact No: " + contactno + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Budget: " + budget + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "Project: " + project + "\n\n";
                                jsonResponse += "App Platform : " + appplatform + "\n\n\n";

                            }

                            txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        hidepDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnArrayRequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="Leads"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResponse"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btnArrayRequest"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:padding="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: JsonArray.length() will give you length of JsonArray.

Comment: Please be precise. Explain what you really need. You have already used response.length() to get the length.

Comment: response.length() all ready give you that.

Comment: Please see json file here you can see "id" only two times appear. & I want after clicking Leads button it should be display count of id only which is two.
Currently i am getting whole json after clicking "Leads " button .

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity.java class, inside method makeJsonArrayRequest(), in OnResponse callback method, you are already getting the size of the array. Look at your for loop,

```
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        // Your code

                        }

                        Log.e("Array Length", response.length()); // Here you will get the length.
```

Where response is your JSONArray.

Comment: Please see json file here you can see "id" only two times appear. & I want after clicking Leads button it should be display count of id only which is two.
Currently i am getting whole json after clicking "Leads " button .

Comment: Store the array length in an 'int' variable and then print it on Button Click

Comment: it is because you are calling the web service on clicking `Leads` button.

Comment: then how will i get ?